# How do I traverse from Builds to Artifacts via Changesets?

Tags: ruby, rally

I can include Changesets in my fetch:

```
query.type = :build 
query.fetch = "Status,Uri,Changesets"
```

But I don't know how to read changests to get the artifacts associated with them. Per API documentation, Changesets collection is not queryiable.

Comment: What Rally toolkit are you using? Javascript, Ruby, .NET? It's difficult to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you get the Builds results, you may iterate over two collections: Changesets on every Build and Artifacts on every Changeset. Here is a Ruby code using rally_api gem that prints out FormattedIDs of associated artifacts:

```
@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :build
query.fetch = "Status,Uri,Changesets,Changeset,Revision,Artifacts,FormattedID"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/workspace/1111.js" }  #use valid OID
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/project/2222.js" }          #use valid OID
query.query_string = "(ObjectID = 3333)"     #use valid OID

results = @rally.find(query)

change_sets = []
artifacts = []

results.each do |b|
    b.read
    puts "Status: #{b["Status"]}, Uri: #{b["Uri"]}"

    b["Changesets"].each do |c|
        c.read
        puts "Revision: #{c["Revision"]}"
        change_sets<<c
    end
end

change_sets.each do |c|
    if (c["Artifacts"])
        c["Artifacts"].each do |a|
            a.read
            puts "FID: #{a["FormattedID"]}"
            artifacts<<a
        end
    end
end
```